# cakephp 2.3 defining data model

Tags: cakephp-2.3

In my data model the main entities are openings (job), companies and students

The company creates an opening so I have a belongsTo relationship which is fine

A student can apply for many openings so to store this I have a link table
openings_students

id|opening_id|user_id

In the Opening model class I have the HABTM association

```
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Applicants' => array(
        'className' => 'Student',
        'joinTable' => 'openings_students',
        'foreignKey' => 'opening_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'unique' => 'true',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Is this all I need or do I need another HABTM relationship on the Student?

Only getting started into the framework so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the best document you go threw is cakephp 2.0

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

I have a question here you are using students table and your foreign key is user_id, are you having two tables users, students or single table students whose foreign key is user_id ?
can you clarify that.